# Simplifying this relationship A*B + conj(A) conj(B)

Tags: simplifying-expressions, complex

How can I force Mathematica to simplify the $A B + A^* B^*$  relationship so that it takes the following form:

$$
A B + A^* B^*=2Re[AB]
$$

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
A B + Conjugate[A] Conjugate[B] // ComplexExpand
```

Edit: after the comments by @J. M.'s ennui the following is in order. The above assumes that both `A` and `B` are real, which might not be the case always. The proper generalization is given below which is taken directly from the relevant comment

```
ComplexExpand[A B + Conjugate[A] Conjugate[B], {A, B}, TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}]
```

Comment: This assumes `A` and `B` are real. If they aren't: `ComplexExpand[A B + Conjugate[A] Conjugate[B], {A, B}, TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}]`.

Comment: @J.M. yes, you are absolutely right. I went too fast. Do you like to post your answer and I can delete mine?

Comment: @RagabZidan did you run it in mathematica notebook and it failed? in mine it worked

Comment: I'd prefer you edit your answer.

Comment: @DiSp0sablE_H3r0  your answer gives (-2 Im[A] Im[B] + 2 Re[A] Re[B]), is that right??

Comment: `Simplify[ComplexExpand[A B + Conjugate[A] Conjugate[B], {A, B}],
 Re[A*B] == ComplexExpand[Re[A*B], {A, B}]]`